# Why bottom toolbar(footer) overlaps my content?

Tags: html, css

I want to create sticky bottom toolbar that always stays at the bottom. It always should be visible on a screen. I tried to use `position: fixed, bottom: 0` which definitely helped, but it overlaps my content. Here is how it overlaps (look at the bottom of the page):

[image]

Yes, I understand that it should overlap, but the problem is that I cannot scroll to bottom to see remaining text.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .bottom-toolbar {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
        </div>

        <div class="bottom-toolbar"> 
            <p> My toolbar </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just add padding-bottom to `.container`

Comment: Can you explain me why exactly to `.container`? I thought that `.article` should have bottom padding?

Comment: There may be other elements in .container, so if there is no article, than you want to be sure the footer does not cover them. Additionally, since `.bottom-toolbar` is fixed, you can probably move it down, before `</body>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footer is on top of the layer with the article text, so you can solve it by "making room" with some padding:

```
.article {
    padding-bottom: 40px; 
}
```

`40px;` is just enough in a codepen, but add however much you want.

Comment: Suppose, my `.bottom-toolbar` height is 7.5%, then what is bottom padding of `.article` should be? 7.5% didn't help.

Comment: 7.5% height will calculated relating to it's parent height. % padding will calculated relating to it's parents width. So, they r not will be same amount.

Answer (score 1):

> position: fixed; always relative to viewport
>   or, you can also use margin bottom to .article or padding-bottom: 60px (or your fotter-bar height) to .container.

- if choose to give margin, do in .article
- or, if choose to give padding, do it in .container or body (bcz fixed positioned is relative to viewport & after container if any other div comes)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        .bottom-toolbar {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: yellow;
        }
        .article {
          margin-bottom: 60px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="article">
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum... Lorem....(a lot of text here)</p>
        </div>
        <div class="bottom-toolbar"> 
            <p> My toolbar </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why giving `padding-bottom` to container does not move `bottom-toolbar`(even if it is inside `container`)?

Comment: when u give 'position: fixed' to any div, it comes out of it's parent div (.container) & lost its own space which was his own inside his parent div. It floats on screen & does not relate to any html element. It only know the screen as his parent. Now, no bottom-toolbar is inside container now. we just need to make space in .container equivalent to .bottom-toolbar to skip hiding it's (.container's) contents. @neo